# Babel not transforming decorators

Tags: gulp, ecmascript-6, babeljs, aurelia

Forgive me if I'm missing something obvious, I'm relatively new to javascript, ES2015, etc.

I have a gulp task to run `gulp-babel` over my `Aurelia` application.  Everything runs and works, except the files containing decorators (Aurelia's `@inject`)

those files spit out the same error in gulp-notify:

> Error: (**path-to-file**)/nav-bar.js: Property right of AssignmentExpression expected node to be of a type ["Expression"] but instead got "Decorator"

I'm not really sure how to begin resolving this.  My task looks like:

```
 gulp.task('build-system', function () {
    return gulp.src(paths.source)
          .pipe(plumber({errorHandler: notify.onError("Error: <%= error.message %>")}))
          .pipe(changed(paths.output, {extension: '.js'}))
          .pipe(sourcemaps.init({loadMaps: true}))
          .pipe(babel(compilerOptions))
          .pipe(sourcemaps.write({includeContent: true}))
          .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.output));
 });
```

and my `compilerOptions`:

```
 module.exports = {
   moduleIds: false,
   comments: false,
   compact: false,
   presets: ['es2015'],
   plugins: ['syntax-decorators', 'transform-decorators']
 };
```

any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe this is a babel v6 issue. (which is implied by your `presets: ['es2015']`)

If you drop back to babel v5.x (as included with the skeleton) it should work.

Here's [the decorator issue](https://phabricator.babeljs.io/T2645) in the Babel Phabricator instance.  It may be some time before it's fixed based on [this reply](https://twitter.com/sebmck/status/661501967412301824).

Comment: Thanks @MichaelMalone.  Uninstalling `gulp-babel` then installing `gulp-babel@5.3.0` fixed the issue!  Glad to know it wasn't something I was misunderstanding.